# Monitor Pending Celery Tasks

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, djcelery

I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ backend. How can I monitor and get the number of pending tasks? "celery events" and djcelery shows the running and completed tasks. Should I be monitoring RabbitMQ? If so how?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using RabbitMq as broker, I recommend to use for that rabbitmqctl ( usually /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl ). So command:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

Shows you number of tasks in queues.
Other solution is installing rabbitmq-plugins: management plugin.
You can do it with:

```
rabbitmq-plugins list
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Your rabbitmq-server will provide webagent where you can easily manage your rabbit-server.

Comment: I did these. But according to Celery, each task result is put in a different queue in RabbitMQ. If I have thousands of tasks, RabbitMQ shows thousands of queues, each corresponding to one task.

Comment: It's very specific installation. PLease check your celery config, I think its not correct

Comment: It's possible I misinterpret it. Here it says: "Every new task creates a new queue on the server, with thousands of tasks the broker may be overloaded with queues and this will affect performance in negative ways." http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-result-backends

Comment: Is there a way to access this from celery? from a python script instead of cli